# React - Testing function passed in as props is called via button press

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am attempting to unit test a simple component that calls a function passed into it.

It is a simple footer component with two button, cancel/save.

When save is  pressed, it should call the "handleSubmit" property I have passed into it but when attempting to test with jest, I cannot get the tests to pass.

Component:

```
function GSFooter({
  handleSubmit,
}) {
  return (
    <Footer>
      <FooterActionsWrap>
        <CancelButton className="update-btn">
          {" "}
          <Link to={"/invoices"}>Cancel</Link>
        </CancelButton>
        <button
          onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}
          className="wp-btn update-btn"
          data-testid="submit-button"
        >
          Save Changes
        </button>
      </FooterActionsWrap>
    </Footer>
  );
}
```

and the test file

```
  let handleSubmitMock = jest.fn();

 test("it should run", () => {

    const {container} = render(<GSFooter
        handleSubmit={handleSubmitMock}
        errors={{}}
      />);

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId(container, 'submit-button'));
    expect(handleSubmitMock).toBeCalled();
  });
```

output:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  36 |     const submitButton = getByTestId(container, 'submit-button');
  37 |     fireEvent.click(submitButton);
> 38 |     expect(handleSubmitMock).toBeCalled();
     |                              ^
  39 |   })
  40 | });
  41 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

After discussion with @cw23, he figured out that he's using `onSubmit` which is only triggered with `fireEvent.submit` instead of `fireEvent.click`! This is very useful info for developers facing a similar problem.

**OLD ANSWER**

You should call `getByTestId` directly. `container` is usually referred to DOM elements

```
test("it should run", () => {

    const { getByTestId } = render(<GSFooter
        handleSubmit={handleSubmitMock}
        errors={{}}
      />);

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('submit-button'));
    expect(handleSubmitMock).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Getting the same output unfortunately

Comment: Could you put `expect(getByTestId('submit-button')).toBeInTheDocument()` before `fireEvent`? That will help you verify that element in the document or not. @cw23

Comment: that test passes, drills through and fails on the handleSubmitMock line

Comment: ahhh instead of fireevent.click, it was fireevent.submit

Comment: where do you put `let handleSubmitMock = jest.fn();`? If you put it outside of function and then you call `clearMocks`, all your mocks will vanish. @cw23

Comment: ohhhh I didn't notice that either, I thought you was using `onClick`, glad that you found out!  @cw23